# Switch HDD mode from RAID to IDE

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, bios, raid, pata

I made an ghost of 2 drives that were installed as raid 0

I made a ghost to one big drive.

Now in the bios, the big drive can only run in raid0 modus.

Is there a easy way so I can run this drive as an single disk ?

Or will I have to re-copy everything again ?

Comment: seems like your case at this [forum](http://community.norton.com/t5/Other-Norton-Products/Using-Ghost-14-to-image-a-RAID-0-array-to-non-RAID-drive/td-p/38233), last post

Comment: You forgot to describe the problem at all! You say "in the bios, the big drive can only run in road0 modus". But what does that mean? Does that mean you can't set the mode to IDE in the BIOS for some reason? If so, why? Or does that mean you can set it to IDE mode but then it doesn't "run?" But what does that mean? What goes wrong? How far do you get?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After 4 full days I finally found a solution!

Anyone who wants to change their RAID mode back to IDE mode in the BIOS, the standard procedure of changing it in the BIOS and a reboot won't work. You will have a Blue Screen of Death (BSOD) all the way.

**You HAVE TO EDIT THE REGISTRY. That is the solution!** To get into the Registry on a working Windows system, press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to bring up the Run dialog. Type `regedit` and press <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Follow this procedure from [this link](http://www.overclock.net/t/1227636/how-to-change-sata-modes-after-windows-installation), which states to change these values under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Currentcontrolset\services\`:

- `adpahci` key, the start value from **3** to **0**
- `atapi` key the start value from **3** to **0**

Comment: "*To bad people are rating this question down...just because they don't know what I'm talking about.*" That's a perfect reason to vote a question down. If the questioner doesn't explain what he's talking about, there's no way people can give him a useful answer. (See my comment to the question for an explanation of why nobody could tell what your actual issue was. It appears from the answer that your actual problem was a BSOD, but you never mentioned a BSOD in your question and so, of course, never told us which BSOD it was.)